# github redirect_uri with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, router, github-api

I'm trying to add login with github in my app. So while testing on my local machine, I set my callback url like this `http://localhost:8000/login/callback/`.

And after that, I add a login link to my page like this, `<a href="https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=user&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/login/callback">Login</a>`, and also

```
$routeProvider.when('/login/callback', {
  controller: 'loginCtrl'
});
```

It success returned me a code with a link like this: `http://localhost:8000/login/callback?code=cd07ff3b70f5d1d1b8a2`. But **angularjs** can not response correctly.

```
Error response

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.
```

I've also tried to set my redirect_url to `http://localhost:8000/#/login/callback`, but the return link is like this **`http://localhost:8000/?code=61e9c8b73c073a0bccc0/#/login/callback`**

I need the code to be appear at the end of the url but not in the middle so that I can use `$location.search().code` to get my code. How can I set it properly?

Like change my redirect_uri or change my router?

Comment: Perhaps I'm suffering the same error. I set up an angular app using yeoman, and added a second view. Then I found the links weren't working.

Answer (score 1):

@lowerkey I still don't know how to handle this but I think that's because the page was **reloaded**.

When you are not setting the `html5Mode` to `true`, then will be `#` at the url, and if you reload the page, the `#` will track the information to the `$scope` to work with the `htmlHistory` api so that the app can work properly even with the page refresh.

But once you set the `html5Mode` to `true`, then there's no `#` to store any `$scope` information, and when the page reload, angular can not found the accordingly scope so it return `404`.

You can check [$location section on angularjs guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location), it has a section explaining why this happen.

> #### Page reload navigation
>
> The $location service allows you to change only the URL; it does not allow you to reload the page. When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, please use a lower level API, $window.location.href.

Answer (score 0):

we should somehow push github to send params in html5-friendly way, i.e.

```
/login/callback/:code
```

for now I've created my hack-solution for it:

```js
var code = parseUrlParam($location.absUrl(), 'code');
function parseUrlParam(url, param){
  var temp = url.match(param + '=(\\w*)');
  if(!temp[1]){
    return false;
  }
  return temp[1];
}
```